# Memory error in Android after capturing images

Tags: android

In my Android application I'm trying to capture three images and upload this three images. I'm capturing two images one by one no problem but when I capture third images the application crashes with error:

```
09-26 16:17:31.398: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24115): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
09-26 16:17:31.398: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24115):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
09-26 16:17:31.398: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24115):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:459)
09-26 16:17:31.398: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24115):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:271)
09-26 16:17:31.398: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24115):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:296)
```

How can I solve the error like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]bitmap+size+exceeds+VM+budget

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Strange out of memory issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue)

Comment: There is a link-only answer provided below [here](http://mobi-solutions.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-if-you-want-to-create-and.html), which I think will be deleted in due course. I'm linking to it here to preserve it.